# Map type presto

Tags: sql, presto

I'm using presto for the sql and the code below is not working, I've tried json extract too, that's also not working with presto, could you guys please help me with this code so that it work on presto

```
SELECT
    city_id,
    value_map,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN map_value(value_map, 'custom.rider.flexProductCell.cellIndex') IN ('0', '2')
        AND map_value(value_map, 'custom.rider.flexProductCell.keys.vehicleViewId') IN ('20054133', '20054595', '20055263')
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS top1_top3_product_count
FROM rider.fact_rider_app_event
GROUP BY city_id, value_map;
```

Comment: What is the result `select typeof(value_map) from ...`?

Answer (score 0):

map_value is not a native presto function.
Something like this should work.

```
SELECT
    city_id,
    value_map,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN CAST(json_extract_scalar(value_map, '$.custom.rider.flexProductCell.cellIndex') AS VARCHAR) IN ('0', '2')
            AND CAST(json_extract_scalar(value_map, '$.custom.rider.flexProductCell.keys.vehicleViewId') AS VARCHAR) IN ('20054133', '20054595', '20055263')
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    ) AS top1_top3_product_count
FROM rider.fact_rider_app_event
GROUP BY city_id, value_map
```

Comment: Thank you, but element_at worked fine for this one.